# How can I display which column has the latest date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My employers often have me run reports directly off of our databases, and I seem to have run into a snag on one of them. I need to find out whether a claim is logged in or out of our system and we have 2 different columns (Log_In_Date and Log_MAIL_Date) in the table that tracks our claims (Claimlog) for part of a report that I am generating.

```
CREATE TABLE CLAIMLOG(
   LOG_DEALER    VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,LOG_IN_DATE   VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,LOG_BATCH     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LOG_BSEQ      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LOG_CLAIM     INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LOG_CSEQ      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LOG_MAIL_DATE VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,LOG_NUMBER    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,LOG_TYPE      VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
  ,LOG_DELETE    VARCHAR(1)
  ,LOG_REJECT    VARCHAR(1)
  ,LOG_CLAIM_SUB VARCHAR(2)
  ,LOG_RO_DATE   VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,LOG_ID        INTEGER  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('OH025',  '2017-06-01 00:00:00',533996,1, 682543,1,'2017-06-06 00:00:00',43,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-30 00:00:00',2393818);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('OH025',  '2017-06-01 00:00:00',533995,1, 682581,1,'2017-06-08 00:00:00',90,'R',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-30 00:00:00',2393819);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('163369', '2017-01-30 00:00:00',486838,8, 117664,1,'2017-01-31 00:00:00',32,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-01-27 00:00:00',2239381);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('132729', '2017-09-11 00:00:00',573238,13,239381,1,'2017-09-14 00:00:00',56,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-09-07 00:00:00',2519220);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('08285',  '2018-05-14 00:00:00',671898,1, 239381,1,'2018-05-17 00:00:00',33,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2018-05-10 00:00:00',2819892);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('06240',  '2013-11-15 00:00:00',780029,1, 239381,1,'2013-12-13 00:00:00',4, 'C',NULL,'X', 'A', '2013-11-11 00:00:00',944206);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('04839',  '2018-06-07 00:00:00',681150,1, 239381,2, NULL,                1, 'C',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2018-04-11 00:00:00',2785317);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('04839',  '2018-04-16 00:00:00',660798,1, 239381,1,'2018-04-30 00:00:00',53,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2018-04-11 00:00:00',2785317);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01563-5','2017-05-31 00:00:00',533928,3, 387468,1,'2017-06-01 00:00:00',85,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-30 00:00:00',2393813);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01563-5','2017-05-31 00:00:00',533928,2, 387462,1,'2017-06-01 00:00:00',85,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-30 00:00:00',2393816);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01563-5','2017-05-31 00:00:00',533928,1, 387358,1,'2017-06-02 00:00:00',85,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-26 00:00:00',2393814);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01563-5','2017-05-31 00:00:00',533927,2, 387458,1,'2017-06-01 00:00:00',4, 'R',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-30 00:00:00',2393811);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01563-5','2017-05-31 00:00:00',533927,1, 387290,1,'2017-06-01 00:00:00',4, 'R',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-24 00:00:00',2393810);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01563-5','2017-05-31 00:00:00',533926,2, 387257,1,'2017-06-01 00:00:00',4, 'C',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-24 00:00:00',2393815);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01563-5','2017-05-31 00:00:00',533926,1, 386930,1,'2017-07-05 00:00:00',4, 'C',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2017-05-17 00:00:00',2393812);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01429-4','2014-09-12 00:00:00',179427,2, 32051, 1,'2014-09-19 00:00:00',12,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2014-09-04 00:00:00',1239381);
INSERT INTO CLAIMLOG VALUES ('01087',  '2015-02-20 00:00:00',239381,1, 45427, 1,'2015-02-24 00:00:00',11,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2015-02-19 00:00:00',1431193);
```

I originally used a case statement:

```
SELECT LOG_DEALER,
 LOG_CLAIM,
  CASE WHEN Log_In_Date > Log_Mail_Date THEN 'In' ELSE 'Out' END AS 'Log In Status'
FROM CHANGELOG
```

This worked for the most part, but I've run into some duplicate results with both "In" and "Out" returns. After doing some research, I adjusted the query to:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LogInDate > COALESCE(LogOutDate, '2000-01-01') THEN 'In' ELSE 'Out' END AS 'Log In Status'
```

to account for null values.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the return of both In and Out for the same entries:

```
  LOG_DEALER   LOG_CLAIM   LoggedInStatus  
 ------------ ----------- ---------------- 
  04839        239831      In              
  04839        239831      Out             
  01563-5      387468      Out
```

I've tried replacing `COALESCE` with `NOTNULL` and rewriting the select statement as:

```
SELECT IIF(LogInDate > LogOutDate, 'In','Out')
```

Still no luck getting the results. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to properly query this?

Comment: Sample data and current result. Please attach it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You can't possibly be getting two values on a single row. My guess is you need some aggregation. Without sample data and desired output this is guesswork. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about that. Updated.

Comment: Your table would contain 1 record for IN and 1 record for OUT, correct? You only want the latest?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to get

Answer (score 0):

According to the sample data and query, LOG_MAIL_DATE has the constraint NOT NULL. This is preventing the insert of the following values:

```
    INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('04839',  '2018-06-07 00:00:00',681150,1, 239381,2, NULL,                1, 'C',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2018-04-11 00:00:00',2785317);
```

Also, the values inserted have duplicate rows for LOG_DEALER = '04839'. By default, SQL Server considers NULL to be the highest value. Therefore, for the two rows, the following results occur:

1. Here, Log_In_Date = '2018-06-07 00:00:00'and  Log_Mail_Date = NULL
   Since NULL > '2018-06-07 00:00:00', It results in LoggedInStatus = 'Out'

   ```
   INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('04839',  '2018-06-07 00:00:00',681150,1, 239381,2, NULL,                1, 'C',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2018-04-11 00:00:00',2785317);
   ```
2. The second case yields Log_In_Date > Log_Mail_Date. Therefore the condition satisfies and results in LoggedInStatus = 'In'.

   ```
   INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('04839',  '2018-04-16 00:00:00',660798,1, 239381,1,'2018-04-30 00:00:00',53,'M',NULL,NULL,NULL,'2018-04-11 00:00:00',2785317);
   ```

Comment: "By default, SQL Server considers NULL to be the highest value." - can you elaborate on this more?

Comment: Wouldn't COALESCE(Log_Mail_Date, '2000-01-01') take nulls into account?

Comment: @petepauletto. Yes, the COALESCE works. And it is working fine in your case too. You have both the 'In' and 'Out' outputs because you have two rows with LOG_DEALER = 04839 and LOG_CLAIM = 239831.** Scenario1:** `SELECT  CASE WHEN '2018-06-07 00:00:00' > COALESCE(null, '2000-01-01  00:00:00') THEN 'In' ELSE 'Out' END AS 'Log In Status' `--> Result = 'In'. **Scenario2:** `SELECT  CASE WHEN '2018-04-16 00:00:00' > COALESCE('2018-04-30 00:00:00', '2000-01-01  00:00:00') THEN 'In' ELSE 'Out' END AS 'Log In Status'` --> Result = 'Out'

Answer (score 0):

Try using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT LOG_DEALER,
 LOG_CLAIM,
  CASE WHEN MAX( Log_In_Date ) > COALESCE( MAX( Log_Mail_Date ), '2000-01-01') THEN 'In' ELSE 'Out' END AS 'Log In Status'
FROM #CLAIMLOG
GROUP BY LOG_DEALER, LOG_CLAIM
```

This will return only distinct `LOG_DEALER, LOG_CLAIM` combinations. By using `MAX` you will be picking up latest dates:

```
LOG_DEALER       LOG_CLAIM   Log In Status
---------------- ----------- -------------
01429-4          32051       Out
01087            45427       Out
163369           117664      Out
04839            239381      In
06240            239381      Out
08285            239381      Out
132729           239381      Out
01563-5          386930      Out
01563-5          387257      Out
01563-5          387290      Out
01563-5          387358      Out
01563-5          387458      Out
01563-5          387462      Out
01563-5          387468      Out
OH025            682543      Out
OH025            682581      Out
```

I also hope that you are not storing dates as `VARCHAR`.